# Listing variables in workspace in Matlab following a certain pattern and store them in a cell array

Tags: matlab

I have 5 variables in my workspace named:

```
testahello
testbhello
testchello
testdhello
testehello
```

How can I build the [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) `{'testahello'; 'testbhello'; 'testchello'; 'testdhello'; 'testehello'}`?

[`who test*hello`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/who.html) returns:

```
>> who test*hello

Your variables are:

testahello  testbhello  testchello  testdhello  testehello
```

But I don't know how to build a cell array from this output, or whether there exists a more suited function than `who`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function-form to call WHO:

```
>> c = who('test*hello')
c = 
    'testahello'
    'testbhello'
    'testchello'
```

Basically [there are two ways to call functions in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html), the command syntax and the function syntax. The first doesn't allow to capture return values in variables.